# C++ console free text input (with max character size)

Tags: c++, string, console

I have an object with a `std::string` field `notes` that allows a maximum of 100 chars. I need to write a C++ console interface (using `IOStream`) to let the user input these notes. All characters are allowed, including of course spaces.

What's the best way of doing such thing?

Is there a way to let the user know how many characters are left?

EDIT: Also empty string should be allowed

Comment: For strong real-time keyboard control, you will need to control the terminal. This is platform-specific, but check out the `ncurses`/`pdcurses` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::string` and `std::getline`.

You can display one hundred asterisks this way:

```
cout << "  " << string( 100, '*' ) << endl;
cout << "> ";  getline( cin, line );
```

then, with a sufficiently wide console window, the user can see how much space remains.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) can be strongly limited in its capacity (the `max_size` member function gives a big number). If you really want to limit to 100 characters (which is not a very good thing to do), using a `char buf[100];` (or perhaps a `std::array`) could make more sense (but don't forget to have a terminating null character).

And to input that field, you may want to use the [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) member function of your input stream.

If you are coding on Linux a console application, the [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/) library could be useful to you. Or perhaps the [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library

Comment: Well, the object would check the length of the string and throw an exception if it exceeds. I don't really want to limit to 100 characters, but that's the specs...